# Pass Parameters from vba to vbs

Tags: vba, vbscript

I'm trying to pass arugements to my vbscript from vba.

```
Shell "wscript C:\test.vbs " & strName & fileDir
```

But in the vbs its taking it as one arguement. How to pass two different arguements.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you had to insert a space at the end of `"wscript C:\test.vbs "` you will also need a space between two variables

```
Shell "wscript C:\test.vbs " & strName & " " & fileDir
```

You will however get problems if either strName or fileDir already contains spaces. If you can not rule that out (e.g. because you know exactly what the names and directories will be) you need to wrap the arguments in quotation marks:

```
Shell "wscript C:\test.vbs """ & strName & """ """ & fileDir & """"
```

The reason this looks so weird is because as quotation marks mark the end and beginning of a string they have to be "escaped" if you want to actually have them as part of the string. The escape character is another quotation mark.

Comment: Great! If you are happy with the answer you can accept it by clicking on the check mark left of it